# How to update field with leading sign

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table where I need to insert a '*' sign before a lot of names. My table looks like this now:

```
id,name

1,cake
2,car
3,mountain
```

And it should be:

```
id,name

1,*cake
2,car
3,*mountain
```

The name column is nvarchar. I have the ids in a csv file. I thought I could make the update statement with concat and a where clause with the IDs, but I can't get it to work.

I tried

```
UPDATE table
SET    NAME = concat('*', NAME)
WHERE  id = '1'
        OR id = '2'
```

But got

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 11 'concat' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name

Comment: Get the `IDs` into a temporary table `tempIDs(id)`, use then `UPDATE my_table SET name=concat('*', name) WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tempIDs)`

Comment: update table

    set name = concat('*',name)

    where id = '1' or id = '2'

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 11
'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Its and MSSQL 2005 instance :(

Comment: As @joanolo suggest import whole csv file into a temporary table, and then update the related records.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. Used the + sign in instead of the concat function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Begin Tran
    Create Table #TEMP(id INT,name NVARCHAR(50))

        INSERT INTO #TEMP
        SELECT 1,'cake' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2,'car' UNION ALL
        SELECT 3,'mountain'

        UPDATE #TEMP
        SET    NAME = +'*'+ NAME
        WHERE  id = '1' OR id = '2' 

        Select * from #TEMP

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: CONCAT Is Not A Build Function for SQL SERVER 2005 & 2008 But It is Available in Updated Version Of SQL Server like 2012,2014,2016